# Terragrunt error message when trying to impersonate account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

I am setting up Terragrunt on our project to be able to plan and apply multiple modules at the same time. We are on GCP. Terraform uses a service account dedicated to our CI/CD (one per env) which will impersonate another service account who have the rights to access and manage resources in our environment.

To do that, I setup two env variables:

- GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS -> link to the JSON file containing credentials for the first service account
- GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT -> service account's email to impersonate

This setup is working successfully with Terraform. However, when trying to init with Terragrunt (`terragrunt init`), Terragrunt try to access the backend (bucket where the state file is located) with the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS account (which does not have rights to access the bucket), ignoring the GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT env variable. To fix that, I specified the *impersonate_service_account* arg.

This is my terragrunt.hcl file :

```
remote_state {
  backend = "gcs"
  generate = {
    path = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite"
  }
  config = {
    skip_bucket_creation = true
    bucket = "my bucket"
    prefix = "state prefix"
    impersonate_service_account = "my service account email"
  }
}
```

I'm now getting another error message, in the lines of: "*Impersonate: status code 403, Request had insufficient authentication scopes, reason: ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT, domain: googleapis.com*".

I never had any problems when impersonating with Terraform, using the same accounts and credentials. Is this a limit of Terragrunt or a misconfiguration from me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So in the same terminal you have tried to use `Terraform` and `Terragrunt` using the same  SA? If you want to check those envs, does both still have value? If you set them on the terminal, it might be erased when you reconnect to the terminal. How did you install terragrunt?

Comment: Yes, Terraform init works. I was working in the same terminal session. Terragrunt was installed as a binary and malade available for all Linux users. It starts successfully when calling it.